# How can i insert a link in my uploaded photo with graph API

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

Can I upload a photo and include a link with Graph API? I just want to include a link to the original post like the Instagram App does. I want it look like this:

```
picture-name -- http://myhost.com/link/to/original/post
```

My code is this:

```
$post_link = get_permalink($post_id);

$file='sample.jpg';
$photo_details = array(
    'message'=> 'Photo message',
    'source' => '@' . realpath($file)
);

$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

I can upload my image to facebook album, but I want to include my post link at the right of `Photo message`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you just need to append the link onto the current message like so?

```
   $post_link = get_permalink($post_id);

   $file='sample.jpg';
   $photo_details = array(
   'message'=> 'Photo message - '.$post_link,
   'source' => '@' . realpath($file)
     );
   $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```